# predictive modeling of cohorted LTV data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I've got a dataset consisting of various install cohorts of an app (e.g. everyone that installed in month X) and these customers' lifetime value (LTV) in the months after they install the app (month 0, month 1, all the way to month 12). It looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lp0tNi-28tZMqBu8BZXUktMvrKQgRVncNifLCCoDcAY/edit?usp=sharing).

Generally speaking, the LTV values follow a logarithmic curve, such that LTV levels out by month 12, if not sooner. However, I only have "complete" data (meaning over the full 12-month lifetime) for the first three install cohorts: July, August, and September 2014.

What I'd like to do is generate predicted LTV values for each cohort after that. In other words, I want to fill in all the 0s in the dataset with predictions based on BOTH information from previous install cohorts, as well as information from the cohort in question.

I've been fooling around with the forecast package in R, but I'm not getting too far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In short, you want to predict the LTV values with respect to time, right?

Comment: yes, exactly right